# Parsing HTML table into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

There is a [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jmxNI7FymUYcVhPR2xp6qmAkZHUBvXgw/view?usp=sharing) (link clickable) file with HTML table. The table is a bank statement. I'd like to parse it into pandas DataFrame. Is there a way to do it more gracefully? I've started to learn Python recently so there is a good chance you guys can give me a good advice.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
with open("sber2.txt", "r", encoding = "UTF8") as f:
    context = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(context, 'html.parser')

rows_dates = soup.find_all(attrs = {'data-bind':'momentDateText: date'})
rows_category = soup.find_all(attrs = {'data-bind' : 'text: categoryName'})
rows_comment = soup.find_all(attrs = {'data-bind' : 'text: comment'})
rows_money = soup.find_all(attrs = {'data-bind' : 'currencyText: nationalAmount'})

dic = {
    "dates" : [],
    "category" : [],
    "comment": [],
    "money" : []
    }
i = 0
while i < len(rows_dates):
    dic["dates"].append(rows_dates[i].text)
    dic["category"].append(rows_category[i].text)
    dic["comment"].append(rows_comment[i].text)
    dic["money"].append(rows_money[i].text)
    '''
    print(
        rows_dates[i].text, rows_category[i].text,
        rows_comment[i].text, rows_money[i].text)
    '''
    i += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df.info()
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
RangeIndex: 18 entries, 0 to 17
Data columns (total 4 columns):
category    18 non-null object
comment     18 non-null object
dates       18 non-null object
money       18 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 656.0+ bytes
       category                                   comment       dates    money
0  Supermarkets  PYATEROCHKA 1168         SAMARA       RU  28.12.2017  -456,85
1  Supermarkets  KARUSEL                  SAMARA       RU  26.12.2017  -710,78
2  Supermarkets  PYATEROCHKA 1168         SAMARA       RU  24.12.2017  -800,24
3  Supermarkets  AUCHAN SAMARA IKEA       SAMARA       RU  19.12.2017  -154,38
4  Supermarkets  PYATEROCHKA 9481         SAMARA       RU  16.12.2017  -188,80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with a *list comprehension* to the rescue:

```
rows_dates = soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'momentDateText: date'})
rows_category = soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'text: categoryName'})
rows_comment = soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'text: comment'})
rows_money = soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'currencyText: nationalAmount'})

data = [
    {
        "dates": date.get_text(),
        "category": category.get_text(),
        "comment": comment.get_text(),
        "money": money.get_text()
    }
    for date, category, comment, money in zip(rows_dates, rows_category, rows_comment, rows_money)
]
```

---

Or, you can do it a bit differently - zipping the lists of texts and specifying the dataframe headers via `columns` argument:

```
rows_dates = [item.get_text() for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'momentDateText: date'})]
rows_category = [item.get_text() for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'text: categoryName'})]
rows_comment = [item.get_text() for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'text: comment'})]
rows_money = [item.get_text() for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'data-bind': 'currencyText: nationalAmount'})]

data = list(zip(rows_dates, rows_category, rows_comment, rows_money))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["dates", "category", "comment", "money"])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```